# Error with Azure Blob Storage Starter API for Spring boot in Java

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage, spring-boot-starter

I have a issue trying to delete a "folder" (blob) from Azure Blob Storage. I have a container and inside that container multiple "folders" (blobs) than contain a big amount of "files" blobs inside.

So, for example, if I have a file called **test.pdf** inside a blob "folder" called **1234** and I go to search the "file" blob **/1234/test.pdf**, I'm able to find it, download it or delete it. But if I search for the blob "folder" **/1234/** I always get an error saying that the blob doesn't exist **"404 BlobNotFound The specified blob does not exist"**.

This is the code I'm using:

```
BlobURL blobURL = containerUrl.createBlobURL(folderName+"/"+fileName);
blobURL.download().blockingGet();
blobURL.delete().blockingGet(); //It Works

BlobURL blobURL = containerUrl.createBlobURL(folderName+"/");
blobURL.download().blockingGet();
blobURL.delete().blockingGet(); // Did not works

BlobURL blobURL = containerUrl.createBlobURL(folderName);
blobURL.download().blockingGet();
blobURL.delete().blockingGet(); // Did not works
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using createBlobUrl it should be a valid url of the blob which refers to the actual blob. If you want to access all the blobs inside a contianer, you should use

```
var blobList= container.ListBlobs(prefix: "folderName/", useFlatBlobListing: true);
```